# Variables inside an frac (expression) in R

Tags: r, expression, quartz-graphics, fractions

I am trying to write an expression in R which needs to have a fraction as well. I need to include a variable that's defined somewhere else in the program inside the `frac()` function in R expression.

```
N <- 20
text(100,2,expression((5-alpha) ~ where ~ alpha == frac(2, 1 +N)))
```

But I am unable to get the value of N inside the frac function to output 20. How to go about doing this?

Comment: Tell us what you're currently getting. Be specific. Also, if you want the actual value of variable `N` substituted, use `substitute()` command.

Comment: I am getting the character "N" as such and not 20.

Comment: I am unable to use substitute inside the frac() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the actual value of variable `N` substituted, use `substitute()` command.